# published android app differs from test environment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

Ive made an app, and published it now. I'm facing a weird problem where the app downloaded from market behaves differently than if i run a test-run through eclipse.

My app launches a maps.google.com url in a webview  like so :

```
 if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://maps.google.com")) {
        mWebView.getContext().startActivity(
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;        }
```

with this as intent:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="helloworld" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

Now when i hit the back button so google maps closes, in my test environment it goes straight back to the page it was on in my main activity. but on the published app, it restarts the entire app, showing splash screen and all.

Ive tried exporting it 4 times now, but can't figure out where the problem lies... anyone have any pointers ?
Just really weird concidering it works as should locally through eclipse ( running on the same physical device).

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project before exporting the APK? Also are you using an emulator or physical device.

Comment: there's no logcat to read, as it only does this on the published app. the test-run show's no error when i try doing this. i'm running it on a physical device (xperia arc).

I will try cleaning it! :)

Comment: There will still be a logcat - it's always there regardless of what you are running or where it came from. Try the `adb logcat` command at the command line when the device is plugged in over USB and running the market version of your app - your test environment in Eclipse (I assume) isn't the only place you can find the logcat.

Comment: Will try.  Now after cleaning it behaves somewhat different.  First time loading the app, the same event triggers, but after that it behaves as i want with no restart. Will try and see what logcat sees :) and thanks for replying.

Comment: well, got a hold off a couple other test devices, including another Arc. Turns out it was just my test device bugging up. everything works as should now, a reboot and some tough love sorted it! Thanks for your replies people! :) 
oh, and in situations like this, what's the best way to close the Topic?

Comment: @Havihavi, just add your own answer explaining what the issue was and then accept it (I think you have to wait a little while - two hours at least). That will let people know that you solved the problem, and what it was so if somebody searches for it later, it will still help them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was phone related, not a code-error. This approach is valid for people trying to do this, but if you encounter any similar bad behaviour on your test device - REBOOT it :)

Big thanks to stackoverflow for having such a friendly, active community.